# A local server that allows mobile users to download and install apps... is such a thing even possible?

Tags: c#, c, networking, download

We will soon have a respectable pool of apps available for our company's employees, we have both flavors: iOs and Android. Those apps have tremendous value for our production and sales teams but are worthless outside the company.

My boss is asking me to develop a server program from which our local mobile users can discover, download and install those apps quick and easy, very much like the App Store and Play Store, but everything inside our local network. I'm not sure if this software is even possible...

Are App Store and Play Store the only possible sources of mobile apps?... If so, which alternatives do I have for this project? If not, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: For iOS, I think you pretty much have to [go to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/), but for Android there are many "Googlable" alternatives.

Comment: Windows phone offers side loading of company apps, which would be convenient for your situation. It's unlikely that you have many (if any) windows phone users, however. Otherwise, @JoachimIsaksson's comment is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into the Enterprise program for iOS:

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Another alternative is signing and sideloading with using MacBuildServer. See these for more information:

http://ios.wonderhowto.com/how-to/sideload-install-open-source-ios-apps-your-iphone-using-macbuildserver-without-jailbreaking-0147456/

[Side loading iPhone apps to device without certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297301/side-loading-iphone-apps-to-device-without-certificate)

Comment: Ok, there is a solution for Apple devices, but how about android, I've being searching on Google, but haven't fond nothing yet.

Comment: I'm not up on Android, but can't you sideload apps on Android devices?

Also, there's this: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en